# Proving Side Congruence Using an Equality

Tags: geometry, triangles

Let's say I have triangles ABC and DEF. Let's also say that segment AC $\cong$ DF. Is there a way to prove that segment AB $\cong$ segment DE by manipulating the following equality:

- AB + BC = DE + EF

I've been manipulating this for some time and keep on ending back at the original equality. I even tried rearranging the triangle inequality theorem:

- AB + BC > AC
- DE + EF > DF

But I can't figure out how to turn that into anything relevant. I isolated the original equality in terms of AB, BC, DE, and EF, but again I kept on ending up where I started. Is it possible to prove AB $\cong$ DE this way?

Comment: Why the statement have too be true at all? $B$ and $E$ still can be arbitrary points, even if $AC\cong DF$.

Comment: This is not true. You can take $A$ and $C$ to be foci of an ellipse, and $B,B'$ any two points on the ellipse. Then $AB+BC=AB'+B'C$, but $AB$ doesn't have to be equal to $AB'$.